# Is c3p0 connection pool is required with hibernate in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x, c3p0

My project is in the beginning stage and I am having a big issue with hibernate. I am using hibernate 4.1.8-Final with c3p0 0.9.1.2.

I have the following entity class:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends Entity {

    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3326144323537452197L;

    private String customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private boolean active;

    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

    @NaturalId
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE", nullable = false)
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

As you can see the `customerName` has been set to `Lob`. Now the first save operation gave me following error:

```
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController] java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at $Proxy240.setCharacterStream(Unknown Source)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,670 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$3$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:83)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,685 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:92)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,685 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,685 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,701 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:57)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,701 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2747)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,701 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2722)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,701 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2929)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,701 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,716 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2936)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,716 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3447)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,716 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,716 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,716 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,732 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,732 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,732 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,732 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,748 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,748 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,748 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,748 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,748 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,763 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,763 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,763 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:756)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,763 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:748)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,779 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:744)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,779 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at com.edfx.adb.dao.base.BaseDao.save(BaseDao.java:21)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,779 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at com.edfx.adb.service.CustomerService.addNewCustomer(CustomerService.java:26)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,779 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,779 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,794 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,794 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,794 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,794 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,794 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,794 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,810 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,810 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,810 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at $Proxy236.addNewCustomer(Unknown Source)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,810 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,810 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,826 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,826 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,826 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,841 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,841 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at $Proxy237.addNewCustomer(Unknown Source)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,841 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController.saveCustomer(AdminController.java:25)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,841 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,841 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,841 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,857 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,857 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,857 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,857 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,857 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,872 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,872 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,872 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,872 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,872 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,888 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,888 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,888 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,904 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,904 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,904 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,904 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,904 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:119)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,919 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,919 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,919 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,919 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,935 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,935 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,935 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,935 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,935 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,950 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,950 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,950 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,950 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
2012-12-15 01:37:25,950 ERROR [com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AdminController]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Briefly the error message is:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V
```

By Googling with this error I found that the first [link](https://community.jboss.org/message/778589#778589) says downgrading to hibernate 4.1.3-Final can solve the issue. And that worked. But my aim is to use latest version of hibernate. I read that hibernate doesn't have much of the connection pooling; cause when it needs connection pool; it will get that pool from the server.

My question is, in a production environment which is running in JBoss AS 7, is it necessary to use third party c3p0; if not I can remove the c3p0; or there is a solution of this issue?

Comment: Using JBoss 7.1, I have upgraded Hibernate to 4.1.8 without any trouble. It is all I can say about it

Comment: @SJuan76, are you using c3p0? what datasource are you using?

Comment: I am using a plain JDBC datasource (SQLServer 2008). Maybe I did missunderstood your question, I thought it was "Is using c3p0 mandatory when using Hibernate?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

please update to c3p0-0.9.2-pre7. It's mature -- unless something unexpected comes up, the next release will be c3p0-0.9.2 final. hibernate recently added some JDBC4 dependencies. c3p0 does not yet have full JDBC4 support (it will, but after 0.9.2 is finalized), but c3p0-0.9.2-pre7 supports these methods to maintain hibernate dependency.

0.9.2-pre7 is a drop-in replacement to 0.9.1.2. simply remove c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar and replace with with BOTH c3p0-0.9.2-pre7.jar and mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.2.jar. or just use Maven central [groupId: com.mchange, artifactId: c3p0, version: 0.9.2-pre7], and let transitive dependency take care of the rest. See the very top of the docs, http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ for downloading info, etc.

c3p0 is not required with hibernate. you can use other Connection pools. but although i am biased, i think c3p0 is a pretty good choice! (i'm c3p0's author.)

Comment: Thank you Steve. We have always used c3p0 as the datasource connection pool, but when I got that error generated by the c3p0 api I was astonished. Using c3p0-0.9.2-pre7 solves the issue. May I have an idea about the release date of c3p0-0.9.2 final? How many days or months left?

Comment: if no big issues arise, then maybe two weeks... pre-7 is basically a "release candidate", i just want to get it kicked around a bit before putting the 0.9.2 series to rest. i'm eager to start the 0.9.5 series, which will include full JDBC4 support (pre7 just has the bit hibernate needs special-cased in.)

Comment: Thanks. I wish we will get it soon. :-)

Comment: 0.9.2 final is already available here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/files/c3p0-bin/c3p0-0.9.2/ (since Feb 9)

Comment: yet 0.9.2-final does not have dependencies of 0.9.2-pre7

Comment: 0.9.2 final supercedes 0.9.2-pre7.

Comment: The latest version of the `hibernate-c3p0` maven artifact still depends on c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1. Is this artifact deprecated now or did they forget to bump the version?

Comment: they certainly ought to bump the version!

Comment: As Steve mentions, ensure to use groupId com.mchange instead of just c3p0. Latest dependency info available here: http://mavendependency.com/project/com.mchange/c3p0

Answer (score 5):

Newer version of hibernate is incompatible with `0.9.1.1`. I use `hibernate-c3p0:4.3.0.CR1` which explicitly depends on `c3p0:0.9.2.1`.

**Possible causes:**

- there might be some other dependency in your project which uses older version of c3p0 as transitive dependency
- Since older group id is `c3p0` and newer is `com.mchange`, maven might have added both of 'em to class path
- By chance the class loader loaded classes from `c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.1` instead of `com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.2.1`(though the groupId changed, the packages are same)

**The solution**

grep for c3p0 dependency

```
`$mvn dependency:tree |grep -B5 "c3p0"`
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.3.0.CR1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
--
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
```

Exclude the older one!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
             <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
             <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
             <!-- Bcoz this version is incompatible with hibernate -->
         </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I don't understand why Maven doesn't show a warning in these cases.

Comment: I had both c3p0:0.9.2.1 and c3p0:0.9.1.1 jar files. After excluding c3p0:0.9.1.1 and adding the exclusion tag my problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

hibernate-core 4.2.8.Final, hibernate-c3p0 4.2.8.Final, c3p0 0.9.2.x.
Had a similar problem: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V

Changed c3p0 version to 0.9.5-pre6 and the problem was fixed.