# java.lang.AbstractMethodError when trying to update

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

I am receiving following exception when trying to update record in Database via Hibernate/JPA:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V is abstract
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$4$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:114)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:57)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2786)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3191)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3126)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3456)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
```

It is thrown when I am trying to update column in Derby DB which is type of TIMESTAMP

Entity is

```
@Entity
public class Tournament implements Serializable {
....
....
 @Column(name = "StartingTime", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar startingTime = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Update call is performed from code :

```
public void setNewTournamentStartDate (short incrementHours, long tournamentId){
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Calendar startingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
       startingDate.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, incrementHours);
       Query query = entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE Tournament t SET t.startingTime = :startingtime WHERE t.id = :tId");

       query.setParameter("startingtime", startingDate);
       query.setParameter("tId", tournamentId);
       query.executeUpdate();
       entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Exception caught ", e);
    }finally {
        entityManager.close();
    } 
}
```

I tried to play around with Date type or sql.Timestamp types in Entity, but still get the same exception on update. Since it is managed entity I also tried just retrieve it and don't use SQL but simply use setter for startingTime but get the same error. Updated pom with most recent entity-manager dependency still the same. Will check if Criteria API will produce different results, but got this feeling that I moving wrong direction and running out of options here.

Comment: Does other transactions work correctly, or this is your first implementation and you get the error? Anyways, please check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885906/is-c3p0-connection-pool-is-required-with-hibernate-in-jboss-as-7) which will probably help you in this error, good luck!

Comment: Yes. All other transactions work well. I can update other types, but when I try to update Timestamp field in database this occurs. I thought it might be related to Hibernate mapping from Java type Calendar to Derby TIMESTAMP, but it also happens when I use java.sql.Timestamp for startingType in entity.